# SQL: Process condition in each group

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table like below.
The rule is, In each group, there is always one person with Code (>0), we can see that person as primary person in group.

In each group, if the primary person with Code > 0 and Status = "active", then we choose this record (Allen in group A).

However, if if the primary person with Code > 0 has Status != "active", then we need to seek other people in its group.

In group B, Amanda has Code but inactive so she is out, in the rest 3 people, the Status of Sarah has higher priority than Joe (Status priority: active -> pre_active -> pending -> inactive), so we choose Sarah and give her code with 2 (same as Amanda, the primary record in this group).

If there are multiple record in group that code = 0 and has same status, then we choose the one on top (by sequence).

In the end, I have to keep 1 record for each group, and give them code number from primary record if the selected record has code in 0.

| Name | Code | Status | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Allen | 8 | active | A |
| Louis | 0 | inactive | A |
| Cindy | 0 | inactive | A |
| Joe | 0 | pending | B |
| Amanda | 2 | inactive | B |
| Sarah | 0 | pre_active | B |

The result should be like below:

| Name | Code | Status | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Allen | 8 | active | A |
| Sarah | 2 | pre_active | B |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the following true: "*In each group, there is always one (and **only one**) person with Code (>0)"*?

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes its true

Comment: What is your SQL implementation (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc)?

Comment: @PM77-1I use Redshift, I think MYSQL is fine in this case, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I did it with two correlated queries, which would not be too efficient.

I also used `GroupCode` field name to avoid escaping the keyword.

In MySQL syntax:

```
SELECT Name, 
       (SELECT MAX(Code) 
        FROM YourTable tbl2
        WHERE tbl1.GroupCode=tbl2.GroupCode) Code, 
        Status,
        GroupCode
FROM YourTable tbl1
WHERE tbl1.Name = (SELECT Name 
                   FROM YourTable tbl3
                   WHERE tbl1.GroupCode=tbl3.GroupCode
                   ORDER BY 
                     --    active -> pre_active -> pending -> inactive
                     CASE Status 
                     WHEN 'active' THEN 0
                     WHEN 'pre_active' THEN 1
                     WHEN 'pending' THEN 2
                     WHEN 'inactive' THEN 3
                     END 
                   LIMIT 1);
```

[**DEMO Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3eb46/12)